# Using Loader inside ActionProvider

Tags: android, action, android-actionbar, loader

Context:
I want an action button that will allow the user to select some stuff form a list.
I'm considering using an ActionProvider for this.
My data is retrieved from a REST service and cached locally in a DB.

Problem: 
ActionProvider doesn't seem to support loaders. (or am I mistaken?)
If I just load the data using a query, it will not get updated once/if the new REST result comes in. In fact, the first time around - it will be empty.

Questions:
0) Is there a way to do what I want in an ActionProvider?
1) Should I be using this approach over a plain old Activity?

PS. Could someone add 'actionprovider' as a tag?  :-)

10X

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a fragment with no UI, but with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` implementation instead.

The fragment could load the data via loaders, and when ready invalidate the options menu, populating it with the required list.

You can attach such fragment to your activity and it will take care of its life cycle, while having this feature in a separate class.